# Dump out Rally View as csv

Tags: rally

I have created a few views in Rally and would like extract the result of these views in an automated scheduled fashion to a folder in a network share. Then have SQL SSIS process ingest that data to SQL tables to be used by PowerBI visualization on a daily basis. Is it possible to access these Rally views via Rally API?

Thanks much!

Comment: There is no special API to retrieve a View. However, you can use appropriate API to retrieve items (defects, tasks and etc) with same criteria as you created a View.

Comment: Thank you! The count of defects I am getting using rest api via .net is less than same exact query using Rally UI gives me a different count.

Comment: It looks like query not the same that's why results are different for API and via Rally UI.

Comment: We are currently researching some options that relate to getting Rally data to tables. Please submit a support case and mention that you received a response to your SO post requesting a connection with our integrations team regarding extracting results of views in an automated scheduled fashion to a folder in a network share via csv.